# How can I using squid from internet

Tags: amazon-ec2, squid

I have a squid running in AWS EC2, it's ubuntu12.04 with 64bit, I tried

```
telnet localhost 3129
```

it can be accessed successfully.

Now I try to telnet from remote machine, it can not.

My question is, how can I access squid server from remote computers? I saw the configuration examples are all 192.168.0.1 or some other internal IP.

Comment: Have you opened the port in your security group? You need to be careful with proxy systems like squid, if configured incorrectly, it will quickly become used as an open proxy.

Comment: Yes, I opened the port in security group, but still can not connect.

Comment: Solved, I changed the squid.conf, set port to 13129.